# Legitimate use-case for macro redefinition

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Reading a chapter on the preprocessor, it stated that redefinition of macros is allowed only if the redefinition matches the previous definition, i.e:

```
#define FOO 0
#define BAR 1+1
#define FOO 0     /* ok. */
#define BAR 1 + 1 /* not ok */
```

I'm baffled by this.

Granted that this behavior is actually correct (the book might be wrong, of course), my question is: Why allow this? I can't think of any legitimate use-cases where this might be used (granted I don't have the experience), is there a rational behind it?

Comment: I believe redefinition may trigger a warning by way of trying to help you avoid programming errors that might be really hard to find otherwise.  For those times when you really want to re-define a macro, use **#undef** to suppress that warning.

Comment: You can use **same macro** in **different header files**. In case two definitions of same macro name are different,  the compiler will warn you about that.

Comment: To @Meninx-メネンックス's point, this happens commonly on large programs with many developers, especially for common mathematical constants like **PI**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to make preprocessor to actively watch repetitive definitions and ensure that they remain identical.

The rationale behind this rule is actually mentioned in the [Rationale to C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf)

> The Committee desired to disallow “pernicious redefinitions” such as
>
> (in header1.h)
>
> **#define NBUFS 10**
>
> (in header2.h)
>
> **#define NBUFS 12**
>
> which are clearly invitations to serious bugs in a program. There remained, however, the question of “benign redefinitions,” such as
>
> (in header1.h)
>
> **#define NULL_DEV /* the first time */ 0**
>
> (in header2.h)
>
> **#define NULL_DEV /* the second time */ 0**
>
> The C89 Committee concluded that safe programming practice is better served by allowing benign redefinition where the definitions are the same. This allows independent headers to specify their understanding of the proper value for a symbol of interest to each, with diagnostics generated only if the definitions differ.

Basically, the idea is to deliberately catch and expose situations when two definitions exist and they are different. If users were always forced to anticipate and `#undef` the previous definition before defining their own, they would quietly override what was not intended to be overridden, without a way to ensure consistency.

By deliberately supplying an extra identical definition you effectively introduce an extra level of protection: if someone modifies the previous definition, the preprocessor will immediately catch and report the resulting mismatch.

In other words by defining

```
#define A 42
```

in your code you are not only defining `A` as `42`, you are also telling the preprocessor that you want to ensure that everyone else (in this translation unit) shares the same idea of what `A` should be.

Comment: Should've looked in the Standard before asking! Thanks, covers my question completely.

Answer (score 1):

Your book is strictly correct but perhaps fails to point out - or you might overlooked it - 
that you may redefine a previously defined preprocessor with no diagnostic provided
that you undefine it before you redefine it. E.g:

```
#define FOO 0
#define BAR 1+1
#define FOO 0     /* ok. */
#undef BAR
#define BAR 1 + 1 /* ok */
```

If you attempt to redefine a macro while it *is* defined there's a high probability
you're committing a blunder and would be grateful for the preprocessor to
draw that to your attention.

When you define a macro in a file that inhabits a large, complex
product codebase - which perhaps has multiple, intertwined build-configurations
controlled by macros that are ultimately defined outside the codebase,
in the build system - then it may be beyond your unaided wits to know that
your definition will never, disastrously, contradict a prior definition in building any
configuration. You'd want to know that, and the preprocessor will tell you.

On the other hand, there are circumstances where you want say: `FOO` *may or
may not have got a prior definition from somewhere at the point where my
file is compiled. Regardless, I want it to have my definition now.
I know what I'm doing and on my head be it.* The preprocessor lets you assume that
responsibility as in:

**foo.c**

```
#include <bar.h>
...

#undef FOO // I don't care what it previously might have been.
#define FOO what I want here
```

and keeps quiet.

In that light, the question of why the preprocessor does *not* complain of
a macro redefinition that doesn't differ from the last one is probably
dispelled. Identical redefinitions are harmless. Useless, yes, but not
necessarily implying that *you*, or anyone, has repeated themselves. Library
header files `libfoo.h` and `libbar.h` might both be included in `baz.c` and
each of them might contain.

```
#define MAX_HANDLES 255
```

which the preprocessor will see twice. But it's harmless, so why complain?

Comment: The standard says "shall not be redefined". An implementation doesn't have to refuse to compile a program with an error (aside from the use of the `#error` directive), but the result is certainly Undefined Behaviour. Implementations which chose to produce warnings instead of errors do not violate the standard, but the program itself falls outside of it. So I'd say that "not allowed" is accurate, although you could also say "not allowed except by some generous implementations"